# POST data and creating REST API with Python/Flask

Tags: python, rest, api, flask, postman

I'm starting with REST API and I need to develop an API to insert values into a PG database.

I will use this API endpoint ("/myendpoint") in an other Flask app with the method :     `r = requests.post('https:/myendpoint', params=payload, verify=False)`

`api.py` :

```
  def insert_values(schema, table_name, list_values):
     cursor2 = connection.cursor() 
     cursor2.execute("INSERT INTO "+schema+"."+table_name+" VALUES "+str(list_values)+ ";")
     connection.commit()




@app.route('/myendpoint', methods=("POST","GET","PUT"))
def insert():
  if request.method == 'POST':
    if request.args['key']=="hello":
      table = request.args.get('table')

      connect_to_db()
      insert_values(schema, table, ('hello','world'))
      #close DB connexion
      close_db_connect()

    return'''<h1>INSERT INTO PG</h1>'''
```

How can I fix the code in order to have my ('hello','world') data directly into the body when I'n testing my connection on Postman ? Thank you

Comment: Any error that you are getting? I see you didn't pass schema into your `insert_values` method.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I can't get the meaning of `How can I fix the code in order to have my ('hello','world') data directly into the body when I'n testing my connection on Postman `. What should be the result?

Answer (score 0):

You're missing values when call method.
`insert_values(table, ('hello','world'))` should be `insert_values(table, ('hello','world'), another_something)` and when you sent `('hello','world')` you're sending a tuple.

If I undestood correctly you should call like `insert_values('my_schema', 'my table',['va1', 'val2'])`.

Then on query `cursor2.execute("INSERT INTO {}.{} VALUES {};".format(schema, table_name, ', '.join(list_values)))`

Comment: I edited my question, actually I want to use my function insert_values like this : insert_values(schema,table, data0 and data is a JSON that I fill manually with Postman in Body>Raw section. In other words, I want to use the function r = requests.post(/myendpoint', params=payload,data) in my future flask application

Comment: Alright, if you're not sendind a list of objects in json you can use ```your_json.keys()``` to access the columns that will be inserted and ```your_json.values()```to get the values